# Boolean preferences problem in Corona Simulator

Tags: lua, sharedpreferences, coronasdk

I'm working on a mobile app using Corona SDK and trying to save settings using `system.setPreferences()`/`system.getPreference()` functions. On my android phone it works fine, but in Corona Simulator it works in the following way:

1. First time, I run the following code:

```
    system.setPreferences("app", {
        test = true
    })
    print(system.getPreference("app", "test", "boolean"))
```

It prints `true`, as expected

2. Second time, I try to get preference without saving it (it should have been already saved in previous step)

```
print(system.getPreference("app", "test", "boolean"))
```

Output is the following:

`ERROR: C:\Users\kezzyhko\Desktop\MobileGame\main.lua:7: system.getPreference() - Preference's string value cannot be converted to boolean.
nil`

3. Trying to get it as string

```
print(system.getPreference("app", "test", "string"))
```

I get `1`

I tried too look into `C:\Users\kezzyhko\AppData\Local\Corona Labs\Corona Simulator\Sandbox\mobilegame-370DE4D889B5BBC98141FE51641482AD\.system\CoronaPreferences.sqlite` file, where preferences are actually stored, and indeed boolean values are saved as `0`/`1`. If in this database I manually edit them to `true`, the code starts working as expected:

```
print(system.getPreference("app", "test", "boolean"))
```

outputs `true`

Is it a known issue (I could not find any info about it)? Is there a way to fix it without dirty workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a technicality. Sure, they are "boolean" in that they are 1s and 0s, but since they are stored in a file, they are probably stored as text, i.e. strings.

So when you load the data, you probably need to always take them in as strings and then manually say that 0 is false and 1 is true.

I'd recommend saving your data using JSON/SQL. Here's a simple tutorial for JSON: https://docs.coronalabs.com/tutorial/data/jsonSaveLoad/index.html